# Why am I getting a 405 error in production but not development?

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, amazon-web-services, nginx, deployment

This is the first project I've built from scratch and first time deploying anything with AWS, ubuntu, nginx. The app is built with postgres, express/node, and react.

When I click the login button in production, I get this error: POST http://18.216.221.221/dashboard/api/1/login 405 (Not Allowed)

But in development the POST request works fine and goes to http://localhost:5000/api/1/login

I can't figure out why in production it's adding the "dashboard" to the URL.

This is the server route:

```
app.post('/api/1/login', async (req, res)=>{
    if (!req.body.username || !req.body.password) {
        return res.status(400).json('missing fields')
    }
    try {
        const result = await db.query("select * from login where username = $1", [req.body.username])
        const isValid = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, result.rows[0].hash);
        if (isValid) {
            res.status(200).json({
                status: 'login successful',
                data: {
                    user: result.rows[0].username
                }
            })           
        } else {
            res.status(400).json({
                status: 'login failed'
            })
        } 
    } catch(error) {
        console.log('unable to login')
    }
})
```

And this is the function for handling the login:

```
const handleLogin = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        try {
            const response = await ClientFilesApi.post(`/login`, {
                username,
                password
            })
            console.log(response)
            if (response.data.data.user === 'myemail') {
                setUserLoggedIn(true)
                setPassword("")
                history.push(`/dashboard`)
            } 
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }   
    }
```

I've set my api baseURL like this:

```
const baseURL = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? "api/1" : "http://localhost:5000/api/1"

export default axios.create({
    baseURL 
})
```

I've followed all the instructions for deploying from this tutorial:
https://github.com/Sanjeev-Thiyagarajan/PERN-STACK-DEPLOYMENT

And this is my source code:
https://github.com/cipdv/ciprmt

Comment: I think you are missing a " / " in your baseURL variable: try `const baseURL = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? "/api/1" : "http://localhost:5000/api/1"`

Comment: Why would that add "dashboard" to the URL?

Comment: Inside your client/src/components/Login/Login.jsx file, in line 25, you are sending it to "/dashboard", also in your server/server.js file, in line 241, you are defining a route with an empty body: //14. display user's dashboard
`app.get('/api/1/dashboard/:id', (req, res)=>{

})`

Comment: Sorry I'm new to this. Shouldn't the line 25 in Login.jsx file just send it to the React route /dashboard after the api request is made and returned a response?

Comment: Yes, it looks like. Are you still receiving the errors?

Comment: Yes, still receiving the errors.

Comment: You can start by consoling the response from your request, also, another way is to test your routes using postman. This will help you narrow down where the problem is coming from

Comment: Honestly if this is your first application, it's kind of big. I recommend you to start with small steps. Try something small which you can learn and understand line by line. Then try building applications on your own

Comment: Everything was working with Postman, and everything works in the development build. The problems have only came to be when trying to deploy a production build.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help by the way. I appreciate it.